# Get views for 3000 posts using GA API?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to use the Google Analytics API to pull the impressions for each page path, while ignoring query parameters. Is this possible? I've looked around the API for some time but it is so complex I'm needing a bit of guidance.

For example:

```
{
  path: '/post-one/',
  pageviews: 500
},
{
  path: '/post-two/',
  pageviews: 5000
},
{
  path: '/post-three/',
  pageviews: 50000
}
```

One important thing is that I'm going to update a `views` table in my own database with the results, and I'm going to look the post up by it's slug (e.g. `post-one`, `post-two`, etc.). That means the API results shouldn't have any query strings or hashes counted separately, it should track all the pageviews together by the page path:

For example:

`/post-one/?x=y`, `/post-one/?x=y#hello`, `/post-one/2` would all be tracked under `/post-one/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pages are actually all predictably named like that, you can use the [`ga:pagepathlevel1`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepathlevel1) dimension to subdivide your results.

Here's a [sample query](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePathLevel1&sort=-ga%3Apageviews) that should get you started: